# How to change the response header when calling api Blazor WebAssembly?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, msgpack

I'm using [MessagePack](https://github.com/lolochristen/MessagePack.WebApi.Client) to deserialize the List of FooViewModel that I'm retrieving through an API

```
 private async Task FooPageChangeHandler(int newPage)
{
    AllData = await Http.GetFromMessagePackAsync<List<FooViewModel>>($"api/FooView/GetAll/{CurrentPage}/{PageSize}");
}
```

After navigating to the page, I get the following error in the console:

> blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'List`1' from content with media type 'text/plain'.

When I look at the response headers, the "Content Type" shows the following:

> content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

How can I go about changing the content-type to be "application/x-msgpack"?

I tried manually adding headers like this:

```
public static async Task<T> GetFromMessagePackAsync<T>(this HttpClient client, Uri requestUri)
    {
        if (client == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(client));

        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUri))
        {
            request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/x-msgpack");
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/x-msgpack");

            var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return await response.Content.ReadAsMessagePackAsync<T>().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```